# UITableView with an array of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, nsarray

Im developing an iOs application and i have an array of objects each object has a name, id, amd describtion. i want to display the name in the table view cell and the description in the detailview controller.
I know there are plenty of tutorial it wouldnt work for my case i think.
Where should implement the array in which class the view controller or the class model or the array class model.

Comment: Why would the tutorials not work? What did you try which proved that?

Comment: @wain they work but not in my project one the array of objects was initialised in the appdelgate and i don't want it to be there. I want to know what is the  class that it should be initialised in?

Comment: Did you try moving that code to your view controller? You need to give details about where the data comes from and where it is used for anyone to say how you should store it...

Comment: If you are new to iOS and Objective-C then I strongly urge you to follow the Stanford iOS course on iTunesU - the latest is "Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad".  The videos and example code will easily allow you to solve problems like this (and much, much more!). In the meantime, I recommend having your data in your model and accessing it via an API in the table view delegate; this will allow you to change the storage to CoreData or something else without touching your controller or view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can start to hard init your array of objects in your tableViewController viewDidLoad.

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *myData;
@end

@implementation TableViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    YourObectClass *myObject;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      myObject = [[YourObectClass alloc] init];
      myObject.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Object:%d",i];
      [self.myData addObject:myObject];
    ]

  //here you are... now use self.myData as your data source...
}

....

@end
```